# How can I make google sheet automatically update matching cells values when I update any cells in my sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple entries in all my sheets that are a repeat of each other, but this is necessary for what I'm trying to do. I want to make it easy and convenient so that if any entries are updated, it will also update any other cells that contain the same value next to it, in all sheets.

| Item | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Apples | 100$ |
| Pears | 20$ |
| Apples | 200$ |
| Apples | 300$ |

If I were to edit the cell right next to Apples to have the price to 50$, the 3rd and 4th entry's cost will also change to 50$ -- and vice versa. My sheets contain a LOT of entries. I have a feeling this might need some JS. I'm just wondering if it's even possible because my google search didn't bring up what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> if I were to edit the cell right next to Apples to have the price to 50$, the 3rd and 4th entry's cost will also change to 50$

looks like you maybe need VLOOKUP like:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, sheet2!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

where on sheet2 you will have a table of content you need to maintain and B column (B1 where this formula will reside) will update accordingly

Comment: Right, so normally for this type of stuff I'd definitively use vlookup, but I can't for my case. I need the info to be decentralized. So I can't use 1 database sheet I update and have all the other sheet vlookup this database sheet. It needs to be vice versa. So If I update any entry in any of the sheets, it will also update any other identical cells, even if it's done indirectly -- it identifies the cell saying Apples and will update the cell to its right with the new value.

Comment: What I'm thinking at this point is I'll need to make a JS that OnEdit, reads the cell to the left of what I edited in a specified column. Creates a var out of it. Identify any cells that is not the current one that has the same value and change the value to its right. I just want to know if some folks already have any codes for it or if it's even possible so I don't waste time trying to get it to work through trial and error.